# Access global scope for type hinting in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am having trouble with type hinting in Typescript, with the inability to specify a global type.

Take the following example

```
// Builder.ts
module Builder {
  class Block {
    // ...
    function uploadFile(file:File) { /* ... */ }
  }
}

//Blocks.ts
module Builder {
  module Types {
    class Image {
      // ...
      function uploadFile(file:File) { /* ... */ }
    }
    class File {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error when compiling:

> error TS2415: Class 'Image' incorrectly extends base class 'Block'.
>   Types of property 'uploadFile' are incompatible.
>       Type '(file: File) => void' is not assignable to type '(file: File) => void'.

Which is fairly misleading at best.

So in PHP you would specifiy File as \File to get the global file, however I cant find/figure out how to do this in TypeScript.

Logically (to me at least) it would be `window.File`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> however I cant find/figure out how to do this in TypeScript.

This is an open feature request for this : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/983 where you can voice your desire.

Note that there is a current workaround: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/983#issuecomment-66704566

One specifically for your case : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27433864/390330

Comment: Thanks, I am surprised that this is still quite a fresh bug, for something that seems quite mature. I am only new to typescript, however I would have thought that any decent sized project would have happened upon these problems well and truly by now.

Comment: Single file with module namespaces are not something that scales in JavaScript / TypeScript. You are much more likely to start using external modules much sooner : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1 that bypass this problem

Comment: I understand the concept, however the files are still validated together in the same project, so even if File and Image classes were in separate files, they are still in the same namespace, and therefor still collide with globals.

Some projects like this one, it doesn't really make sense to split it up too much, because all the files will always be required, and are quite tightly coupled together.